# How to solve linear differential equation with Fourier series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

**The Problem**

I have the following system of linear second order differential equations which I would like to solve:

$$\mathbf{J}\ddot{\mathbf{\Theta}} + \mathbf{C}\dot{\mathbf{\Theta}} + \mathbf{K\Theta} = \mathbf{ T}_t(t) \tag{1}$$

I would like to solve it using the technique involving Fourier series.

---

**My Attempt**

These are the steps I follow:

1. Assume that $\mathbf{\Theta}$ is a Fourier series with unknown coefficients $\mathbf{c}_n$, and finds its derivatives:
   \begin{align}
       \mathbf{\Theta} & = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty} \mathbf{c}_n e^{in\omega t} \label{eq: fourier disp}\\
       \dot{\mathbf{\Theta}} & = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty} (in\omega) \mathbf{c}_n e^{in\omega t} \label{eq: fourier speed} \\
       \ddot{\mathbf{\Theta}} & = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty} -(n\omega)^2 \mathbf{c}_n e^{in\omega t} \label{eq: fourier accel} 
   \end{align}
2. Expand the right hand side of Eq.(1) into the following Fourier series with known coefficients $\mathbf{f}_n$:

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{T}_t = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty} \mathbf{f}_n e^{in\omega t}
\end{equation}

3. Substitue all of the above equations from Steps 1 and 2 into Eq.(1), also knowning that $\mathbf{c}_{n}=\mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Re}} + i\mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Im}}$ and $\mathbf{f}_{n}=\mathbf{f}_{n,\text{Re}} + i\mathbf{f}_{n,\text{Im}}$, to get the following:

\begin{gather}
    -(n\omega)^2 \mathbf{J}\mathbf{c}_n e^{in\omega t} + (in\omega)\mathbf{C} \mathbf{c}_n e^{in\omega t} + \mathbf{K}\mathbf{c}_n e^{in\omega t} = \mathbf{f}_n e^{in\omega t} \nonumber \\ 
    %
    -(n\omega)^2 \mathbf{J}\mathbf{c}_n + (in\omega)\mathbf{C} \mathbf{c}_n + \mathbf{K}\mathbf{c}_n = \mathbf{f}_n \nonumber \\ 
    %
    -(n\omega)^2 \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Re}} + i\mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Im}}) + (in\omega)\mathbf{C} (\mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Re}} + i\mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Im}}) + \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Re}} + i\mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Im}}) = \mathbf{f}_{n,\text{Re}} + i\mathbf{f}_{n,\text{Im}} \tag{2}
\end{gather}

4. Equate the real and imaginary parts of Eq.(2) and create a linear system of equations:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -(n\omega)^2 \mathbf{J} + \mathbf{K} & - (n\omega)\mathbf{C} \\
    -(n\omega)^2 \mathbf{J} + \mathbf{K} &  (n\omega)\mathbf{C}
    \end{bmatrix}
    %
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Re}} \\ \mathbf{c}_{n,\text{Im}}
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{f}_{n,\text{Re}} \\ \mathbf{f}_{n,\text{Im}}
    \end{bmatrix} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

You can probably see this by eye as well, but when I substitute all the numbers to solve Eq.(3) above, the square block matrix is singular. Therefore I am making a mistake somewhere along the way. My hunch tells me that something might be wrong in step 3 but I can't tell what.

Comment: Why are you splitting $\mathbf{c}$ into real and imaginary parts?  It seems to me it would be computationally easier to solve the equation $(-n^2 \omega^2 \mathbf{J} + i n \omega \mathbf{C} + \mathbf{K}) \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{f}$ over the complex numbers instead.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert in retrospect what you say might be a more efficient way of doing it. However as I dont' fully grasp the problem yet, it helps me visualise things and understand them better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation $(2)$ is correct, but equation $(3)$ should be :
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf K - (n\omega)^2 \mathbf J & -n\omega \mathbf C \\
n \omega \mathbf C & \mathbf K - (n\omega)^2 \mathbf J
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf c_{n,\rm Re} \\  \mathbf c_{n,\rm Im}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  \mathbf f_{n,\rm Re} \\  \mathbf f_{n,\rm Im}\end{pmatrix} \tag{3}$$